# Omniture tracklink canceled

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I am trying to track some custom links using:

```
s.tl(this, 'o', 'trackingName')
```

But the tracking call keeps getting canceled (I checked in both Firefox and Chrome network utilily), as it loads the link before the request is completely sent to omniture.

I know `s.tl()` is supposed to have a 500ms delay or until the call is completed, but it's not doing it...

I am using `SiteCatalyst code version: H.26.1`

Something that may be interrupting the flow is the automatic exit link tracking, which I believe is set by `s.trackExternalLinks = true`, I tried to set it to `false` before calling `s.tl()` but it is still performing the exit link tracking (the request completes successfully)

Any clues?

Comment: Are you not seeing the request show up in the UI? Keep in mind the delay, minimum is usually about 20min for us. Also, if you use the firebug extension omnibug, you can see the pixels from the previous page to check for issues.

Comment: @BrettAHale hi, I can't check the UI because my company has set it up so that all calls from the office are ignored... (don't ask...) I checked the network calls with firebug, the request is cancelled before a response is given. Even *if* the server received the full request, I cannot guarantee that the request was sent successfully, it could've only partially sent the headers, or be only at the `ACK` stages of a HTTP connection before it is cancelled. So I must rely on a proper response from omniture to see that it was processed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we ran into the same bug. The best solution seems to be increasing the forcedLinkTrackingTimeout to 500 and creating a custom function to navigate:

```
s.forcedLinkTrackingTimeout = 500;

function navigate(url) {
  window.location.href = url;
}

s.tl(this, "o", "trackingName", null, navigate(this.href));
```